# Does a Jewish great grandmother (mother's side) qualify me to make Aliyah?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

My great grandmother was Gertrude Wirtschafter. She married a non-jew but her mother was jewish and married a jew.  My great-great grandmother was Rose Wirtschafter and her husband was Abram Katz.  I have the birth certificate of my great grandmother which shows the names of her parents. My great grandmother's daughter did not marry a jew.  And her daughter (my mother), did not marry a jew.  So, essentially, i have a direct matrilineal jewish line of descent but the last women in that line that had a jewish husband was my great great grandmother.  Does this make me Jewish and can I migrate to Israel?  I am most connected to the Jewish faith.

Comment: HI @Jeremy Jew, welcome to Mi Yodeya!  This question will likely be closed because we have similar ones to it. From the information you give, though, it looks like you are indeed Jewish and could make aliyah. I hope you stick around and learn with us!

Comment: I'd love to.  Thank you for your kind response. I asked the question because i saw some legal advice online that said, "An aliyah applicant is required to present documented proof of being Jewish or having Jewish ancestors within the last two generations."  I asked because my great great grandmother who married a jewish man was three generations back.

Comment: this isn't the right forum to discuss the fine points of Israeli immigration law, but suffice it to say if you can prove your maternal great-grandmother was Jewish and you are not adopted, then you yourself will be widely accepted as a Jew, regardless of how you were raised

Comment: Thanks.  I'm hoping someone on here knows more about the details of Israeli immigration law that could advise me on this.  Would be a lot cheaper than going to a lawyer.  lol!

Comment: (Note: just those last names on birth/marriage/death certificates won't be enough to "prove" you're Jewish, you've still got a lot of legwork ahead of you)

Comment: Ok, can you give me a clue to any legwork i may need to do?  I know my uncle David - my mother's brother always knew we were jewish.  Yet he had to go thru an orthodox conversion and married a jewish woman.

Comment: My uncle (mother's brother) also became a Rabbi a few years before he passed away.

Comment: Jeremy this is not the forum for this kind of stuff. Find a rabbi to talk to about proving your Judaism, and contact Nefesh b'nefesh or the Jewish Agency about aliyah.

Comment: Will do.  And thanks for taking time to respond to me.

Comment: @JeremyJew Clarifying whether somebody is Jewish or not can get pretty complicated, so its best to ask a rabbi. If you tell me what city you live in I can try to find you a rabbi or beis din (Jewish court) either in your city or nearby.